# Python ternary operator can't return multiple values?

Tags: python

I know it's frowned upon by some, but I like using Python's ternary operator, as it makes simple `if`/`else` statements cleaner to read (I think).  In any event, I've found that I can't do this:

```
>>> a,b = 1,2 if True else 0,0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

The way I figured the ternary operator works is that it essentially builds the following:

```
if True:
  a,b = 1,2
else:
  a,b = 0,0
```

Could someone explain why my first code sample doesn't work?  And, if there is one, provide a one-liner to assign multiple variables conditionally?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's parsing that as three values, which are:

```
1,
2 if True else 0,
0
```

Therefore it becomes three values (`1,2,0`), which is more than the two values on the left side of the expression.

Try:

```
a,b = (1,2) if True else (0,0)
```

Comment: Good ol' "comma operator has lower precedence than the conditional ternary"... Even works in C...

Comment: Any method to do his when doing it as a list? Just returns a single list of length 2 tuples when I use brackets instead of two separate lists.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of operator precedence. Consider:

```
>>> 1,2 if True else 0,0
(1, 2, 0)
```

Add parentheses as needed, and you will get it to work:

```
(1,2) if True else (0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers have already addressed your question, This will explain a method that you can use to understand how python parsing really work.

For that, you can use `ast` module to print the trees of the [Python abstract syntax grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)(I am using python 3.12 here).  If you inspect the AST of the source `a,b = 1,2 if True else 0,0` it looks like the following.

```
>>> import ast
>>>                                   ----------------------------------|
>>>                                   |              |
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("a,b = 1,2 if True else 0,0"), indent=4))  |
Module(                       | |   | ---------------------             |
    body=[                    |  ----------------------    |            |
        Assign(                ----------------------  |   |
            targets=[                                | |   |            |
                Tuple(                               | |   |            |
                    elts=[                           | |   |            |
                        Name(id='a', ctx=Store()),---  |   |            |
                        Name(id='b', ctx=Store())],----    |            |   
                    ctx=Store())],                         |            |
            value=Tuple(                                   |            |
                elts=[                                     |            |
                    Constant(value=1), ---------------------
                    IfExp(                         |                    |
                        test=Constant(value=True), |--------------------
                        body=Constant(value=2),    |
                        orelse=Constant(value=0)), |
                    Constant(value=0)],
                ctx=Load()))],
    type_ignores=[])
>>>
```

If you inspect the tree carefully(I have added few comments to understand how the AST node maps to the actual source) you can see that its's getting parsed as

```
a,b = 1,(2 if True else 0),0
```