# Why unpacking doesn't work correctly when using an one line if-else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, iterable-unpacking

I'm very new to Python and came to a strange behaviour while tested my code. I'm searching over a tree and gather informations, depending on the direction i'm searching the tree.

```
    def my_func():
        return (10,20)

    direction = 'forward'

    if direction == 'forward':
        a, b = my_func()  
    else: 
        a, b = 30,40

    print (f'Direction is: {direction}\nThe value of a is: {a} \nThe value of b is: {b}')
```

This gives me the expected result:

```
    Direction is: forward    Direction is: backward
    The value of a is: 10    The value of a is: 30 
    The value of b is: 20    The value of b is: 40
```

But if i use an one-line if-else-condition the result is strange:

```
    a, b = my_func() if direction == 'forward' else 30,40
```

This gives me the following result:

```
    Direction is: forward          Direction is: backward    
    The value of a is: (10, 20)    The value of a is: 30      
    The value of b is: 40          The value of b is: 40
```

Can anyone explain to me why unpacking doesn't work in this case (forward search)  and why b gets the value from the else branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ternary operator can't return multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622853/python-ternary-operator-cant-return-multiple-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't unexpected. You set `a` to `my_func() if direction == 'forward' else 30` and `b` to `40`. This is because the unpacking is done **before** the ternary operator. Thus, `a` will take the result of the one line if else condition and `b` will take the value `40`.

If you want to fix it, do `a, b = my_func() if direction == 'forward' else (30, 40)`

EDIT: credit to @Jake, who commented at the same time I edited.

Comment: It's probably easier to explain it as:

`a, b = (my_func() if direction == 'forward' else 30), 40`

OP, try putting the final `30, 40` within parens:

`a, b = my_func() if direction == 'forward else (30, 40)`

Comment: This was very well explained from you and Jake. I tried the parens at the end and it indeed works now.  So, many thanks.